# Sub instruction and affected flags on x86: can SUB set SF != CF?

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

Since documentation doesn't really describe how the flags are affected, I couldn't figure out what's the difference between carry and signed flag during sub instruction, it seems like whenever a < b in `sub a, b` both carry and signed flags will be set. Is there a case where signed flag will be set without carry (or vice versa) during sub instruction ?

Comment: Yes, of course. `sub 1, 2` will produce result `-1` which is fine in signed (no overflow) but wraps around in unsigned (hence carry).

Comment: AFAIK, the Intel documentation does describe which flags are affected how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a case where signed flag will be set without carry (or vice versa) during sub instruction ?

Sure:

```
mov al,0xFE
sub al,2
```

The result is 0xFC, which when viewed as signed 8-bit is -4. So the SF will be set, buf CF will be clear (carry can be viewed as "unsigned less than", and 0xFE is obviously not unsigned less than 2).